# Why does GitLab need full access read and write permissions when importing a GitHub repo?

Tags: github, import, gitlab, repository

I just signed up for GitLab, after learning about this cool feature where you can import your GitHub repositories and keep the two in sync. The import feature seems simple enough, but I paused when I got to the step where I authorize GitLab to my GitHub account. Why does it need so many permissions? Some make sense to me, others not so much. Specifically:

> **Personal user data**
>
> Full access
>
> This application will be able to read and write all user data. This
> includes the following:
>
> - Private email addresses
> - Private profile information
> - Followers

I understand why it needs to read and write to all public and private repository data. It's moving all that data to GitLab, and it needs to write to keep it in sync. What I don't understand is why it needs **write** permissions to my email and profile information?

I know that GitLab is a reputable company that didn't just pop up yesterday, but I am still wary when giving full access permissions to any service. If someone could help me understand, that would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but my guess is it *doesn't* actually need all that. Perhaps requesting full access is just easier than requesting all of the individual granular permissions it actually needs.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options when migrating a repository from GitHub to GitLab. You can migrate using only the url, in which case what you’ll have on GitLab is more similar to what you’d get if you simply added an additional remote in the repo - the full repo will be there, but everything specific to GitHub - the pull requests, comments, issues, etc, as well as all users tagged or participating - will be lost.

Alternatively, you can use the GitHub importer. This option fully migrates the GitHub repo to GitLab, setting up the GitLab equivalents of GitHub features (pull requests become merge requests, etc.). And part of this involves assigning users to each comment, mention, PR, etc.

From the [gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/github.html):

> When issues and pull requests are being imported, the importer attempts to find their GitHub authors and assignees in the database of the GitLab instance. Pull requests are called merge requests in GitLab.
> For this association to succeed, each GitHub author and assignee in the repository must meet one of the following conditions prior to the import:
>
> - Have previously logged in to a GitLab account using the GitHub icon.
> - Have a GitHub account with a public-facing email address that matches their GitLab account’s email address.
>
> GitLab content imports that use GitHub accounts require that the GitHub public-facing email address is populated. This means all comments and contributions are properly mapped to the same user in GitLab. GitHub Enterprise does not require this field to be populated so you may have to add it on existing accounts.

So yes, these are required if you want the full GitHub mirror or migration. If you just want the git repo contents, use the import from url tool, and the requirements will be much less extensive.